# Send javascript array through a form on submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

does anyone know if it is possible to append javascript array, that is made with ajax to a form and send it on submit? Because I have to send all data in one call to the route through post.

Here is my Javascript

```js
function ajax(e) {
  const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = "/create-pedido";

  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      let articles = [];
      articles.push(e.target.id);
    }
  }
  http.open("GET", url);
  http.send();
}

let prodClick = document.querySelectorAll('.botonClickeado');
prodClick.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    ajax(e);
  });
});
```

As you see, my code pushes values to an array when I click an object of html. How can I append the array to my form so when I submit it, the data sends and the array too?

Comment: FYI, you can simplify this to: `item.addEventListener('click', ajax);`

Comment: [```XMLHttpRequest.send()```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) should help.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't remember I could do that with ajax, but I need to still send the form data somehow at the same time the array sends, because it is a list of products that goes in an order, so I have to put the order and the array data, together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the data all together you can create a javascript object. Store all your values in this JS object & specify the content type as

```
  http.open("POST",url,true) //true means request sent is asynchronous i.e. we are waiting for the response
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.send(JSON.stringify(<your java script obj name>));
http.send()
```